# Do memory addresses take up memory?

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-address

I am fairly new to programming and am starting to learn the ins and outs of memory allocation.  One question that recently occurred to me that I haven't yet been able to find a clear answer to is do memory addresses themselves take up memory.  For example, in a 32-bit system, the way I understand it is that each address in 4 bytes and they will typically refer to an empty 'bucket' in memory that is capable of storing 1 byte of data.  Does this mean that for each memory location in a 32-bit system, we are actually using 5 bytes of memory(meaning 4 for the address and 1 for the empty bucket)?  I'm sure I am missing something here but any clarification would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: If you are ever storing some memory address in the memory itself, then it takes up the space required to store a memory address. Although there is no *meta-memory* storage that stores memory addresses. That is handled in the hardware. Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_controller) and [this](http://wiki.xtronics.com/index.php/How_Memory_Works)

Comment: Ah-ha!  Thank you.  I haven't gotten all of the way through it yet, but I think the second article in particular told me exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

To reference a memory address you need to express that memory address somehow, and on 32 bit system a memory reference takes 4 bytes indeed. So for any addressable memory address, somewhere else in memory there are 4 bytes that have that address.

But this does not cascade to an x5 multiplication, because a program does not need to reference *every* byte of memory. It only needs the address where something in memory *starts*, and then it can work its way to every byte of that 'something' using arithmetic.

To give an example: you have a string in memory `Justin Foss`. Is it at address 0x10000000, and this address is stored in a variable. So the actual variable value is 0x10000000, pointing to the string `Justin Foss`. But at 0x10000000 you only have one byte, the `J`. At 0x10000001 there is the `u`, at 0x10000002 is the `s` and so on. Your application does not need a variable for each character, it only needs one variable (4 bytes) to the beginning of the string. Same for object (fields): you only store the address where the objects *starts*, and the compiler know how to do the arithmetic to find the field it needs, by adding the necessary offset. In general memory objects are quite large, and a few 4 byte variables in the program reference quite a bit of memory.

Comment: So, I understand the idea that if we were to, say, store a string in a variable we are actually storing the address of the first byte of that string, and the rest of it can be accessed linearly until we reach a null character.  To clarify, what I am curious about is not how much memory we use in a program when storing a reference to a location in memory, but rather does each location in memory inherently use memory itself to store the data which is it's unique address.  Again, I'm sure I'm missing something here so I apologize if this sounds like a silly question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(at the risk of oversimplification) Memory is sequential. Address 123 is the one-hundred and twenty third byte from the first (zeroth) by in the system. There is no memory devoted to indicating byte 123 is 123. The byte that comes after that is 124.